# Wordpress Ajax is Returning a Fatal Error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, fatal-error

I am trying to make an AJAX call in a child theme I am playing around with, and I am receiving the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in

Basically my ajax call goes to functions.php file and in the functions.php I am requiring once the file (ajax.php) with the PHP logic. If in ajax.php file all i am doing is echoing a string, it works fine, but if I try to use an `add_action` function, it then returns the Fatal Error.

Here is some code.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'url to functions.php file',
   data: {'my-ajax': 'something'},
   type: 'POST',
   cache: false,
   success: function(data, status) {
      if(status == "success") {
         $('.container').append(data);
      }
   },
   error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
   }
});
```

PHP - functions.php File:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
      if($_POST['my-ajax'] != "") {
         require_once('prod-cats.php');
         die();
      }
}
```

PHP - ajax.php:

```
add_action( 'testing_ajax', 'testing_ajax_func' );
function testing_ajax_func(){
  echo "Hey There";
}
```

The above code fails, but if I remove everything from the ajax.php file and leave behind the echo, it then works.

What is it with the `add_action` function that is causing the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `add_action` defined?  All you're doing is calling it.  (Which is exactly what this error message means).

Comment: functions.php seems like a "vanilla" php file - ie it doesn't have the wordpress core functions loaded (which include add_action).

Comment: @Tibrogargan but how come if I have the same add_action in the functions.php file and work with (no ajax) I have no issues? And isn't the function right beneath it defining it? Or am I missing something? I do have the "do_action" call in the footer.php file....

Comment: @James wouldn't the parent theme handle this? I thought in a child theme the functions.php files get merged and the paren't function.php file would have the necessary WP core functions. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How is the parent theme being included when you're going directly to `functions.php` via Ajax?  It's not magic

Comment: you have several wrong lines in your code(they don't throwing fatal error, but cause issues with wp ajax requests). first look how to make ajax requests in wp( there are thouthands examples in stackoverflow and in the internet ).

Comment: Your URL is incorrect, you cannot use AJAX in WordPress like that.  You need to read the article about [How to use AJAX in plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) - basically, you should be running a url that looks something like this: `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.